# as_tree in AWS S3 Ruby SDK V2

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In v1 the AWS S3 sdk there was a method called "as_tree" that you could call on a list of objects, and it would return it in a nice Branch/Leaf format that made it easy to traverse. I can't find anything in [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html) for v2 for a method like this. Is there any way to do this in v2?

If not, how can I replicate a similar functionality in v2? I'm fine with writing a new method to create a tree and modifying my code a bit.

Comment: Looks like someone already answered this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284946/amazon-aws-how-to-replicate-tree-branch-functionality-from-aws-ruby-sdk-v1-in-a

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a comment from George M Whitaker gave me a method that would return some of the data I needed. I used this to create my own version of as_tree, so I'll post that here.

```
class S3Node 
end

class S3Leaf < S3Node
  attr_accessor :object
  attr_accessor :key

  def leaf? 
    true
  end

  def branch?
    false
  end

  def initialize(summary)
    @key = summary.key
    @object = S3_BUCKET.object(@key)
  end
end

class S3Tree < S3Node
  attr_accessor :children
  attr_accessor :prefix

  def leaf? 
    false
  end

  def branch?
    true
  end

  def initialize(options) 
    @prefix = options[:prefix]

    @resp = S3_CLIENT.list_objects_v2(bucket: S3_BUCKET.name, prefix: @prefix, delimiter: '/')
    @common_prefixes = @resp.common_prefixes
    @contents = @resp.contents

    @trees = @common_prefixes.map do |common_prefix|
      S3Tree.new(prefix: common_prefix.prefix)
    end

    @leaves = @contents.select { |content| content.key.length > @prefix.length }.map do |content|
      S3Leaf.new(content)
    end

    @children = @trees + @leaves
  end
end
```

Thus you can call S3Tree.new(prefix: 'your/prefix/here') instead of S3_BUCKET.as_tree(prefix: 'your/prefix/here'), and you should have most of the functionality of the old as_tree. In my code I have constatns S3_BUCKET and S3_CLIENT, so you'll need to replace these with your own buckets and clients. Here's the code I use to initialze those if anyone is wondering.

```
S3_RESOURCE = Aws::S3::Resource.new
S3_CLIENT = Aws::S3::Client.new

S3_BUCKET = S3_RESOURCE.bucket(ENV['BUCKET_NAME'])
```